Cartoon - stone creatures live with a woman who is possibly a wizard
I'm looking for an old cartoon. I was very little when I watched it (early 2000's), so I pretty much don't remember anything about it.
The only things I can recall is that there were these stone creatures (like gargoyles) who lived in a tower or a house with this old lady and I think she was a wizard. The gargoyles would sometimes turn into stone.
The colour palette of the show was pastel.
It's not Disney's Gargoyles. That cartoon made it impossible for me to look for my series.

If the stone creatures were small dragons based on the Pocket Dragon ornaments, and the wizard was a man rather than a woman, possibly Pocket Dragon Adventures? Quite a long shot, though.

I don't think that's it. I'll still check it out though, looks cute^^
